# Fit X-axis and scaleXY to keep canvas in center after zooming out

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, konvajs

I would like to use Konva js to accomplish tasks below:

1- Loop data from db and then draw groups on canvas, group contains circle+text

2- When shapes increase, zooming out to keeping them in the middle

The challenge i encountered:

- When shapes exceeds layer width i start zooming out but i can't keeping them in the middle.

How to calcul layer x-axis depend on shapes to keep canvas centred?

How can i calculate the zoom to keep place just for a new shape and not zooming out too much?

Thank you in advance

Please find the: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-d7ken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I have never used `Konva` before so maybe there are other solutions which simpler than this.

Use `getClientRect` bounding of stage compare to its width and height to find the right scale then translate its to center.

```js
const adjustStage = function (stage) {
  let width = stage.width()
  let height = stage.height()
  let scaleX = stage.scaleX()
  let scaleY = stage.scaleY()
  let rect = stage.getClientRect()

  // calculate scale to fit stage on each axis then choose the small one
  let scale = Math.min(
    width / rect.width,
    height / rect.height
  )

  stage.scale({
    x: scaleX * scale,
    y: scaleY * scale
  })

  // get new scaled rect
  rect = stage.getClientRect()

  // calculate distance difference between two centers on each axis.
  stage.move({
    x: width / 2 - (rect.x + rect.width / 2),
    y: height / 2 - (rect.y + rect.height / 2)
  })

  stage.draw()
}
```

Result [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-lni2f?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer! i appreciate your suggestion for $nextTick it's really useful!